# Unique strings in overall iterations of for-loop MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab, loops, for-loop, unique

I'm coding a scenario in which I want unique strings in *Matlab*, i.e each iteration gives unique strings, however I tried a *for loop* iterations for *unique* strings in every iteration (or can say overall results are in the form of *unique* strings) as follows. But it gives unique strings in one iteration only, however I need on every iteration, or overall *loop* iterations.
The bug forms as it *unique* strings by adding 1 but on the next iteration, it conflicts!!!

**My Code (for simplicity, no output is shown):**

```
for ii=1:10

matrix1=['Obj' num2str(ii)];
matrix2=['Obj' num2str(ii+2)];
matrix3=['Obj' num2str(ii+3)];
matrix4=['Obj' num2str(ii+4)];
matrix5=['Obj' num2str(ii+5)];

end
```

*Any suggestions or piece of formula that makes my strings unique are welcomed.*

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish. Could you explain it better? Sounds to me that you're solving a problem the wrong way. To start, if for some reason you're using variables named matrix1..n, you most likely want a cell array, and use matrix{1..5} instead.

Comment: @carandraug that matrix is just for example sake, saving a string in matrix just, the problem is, how can I uniquely declared my strings for overall iterations of for loop.

Comment: @AhsanAli When you say "unique", maybe you mean "random" but within some range of string names?

Comment: @Divakar random may conflict but unique number can't, as for instance, random can generate 5 in first iteration and same 5 in 5th iteration, but unique can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're question is unclear.
Maybe that's what you're willing to do:

```
i = 1;
MATRIX = [];
for iter=1:5
   matrix=['Obj' num2str(iter)];
   MATRIX = [MATRIX ; matrix];
   iter = iter + 2;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If I undertand your question correctly, this is one possible solutuion:

```
for ii=1:10

    matrix1=['Obj' num2str(ii) '-1'];
    matrix2=['Obj' num2str(ii) '-2'];
    matrix3=['Obj' num2str(ii) '-3'];
    matrix4=['Obj' num2str(ii) '-4'];
    matrix5=['Obj' num2str(ii) '-5'];

end
```